# How Can I publish the Docs to Github pages after generating it via Dokka (Kotlin)?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, dokka

I've successfully generated the Kotlin doc using [Dokka](https://github.com/Kotlin/dokka) for Android projects. Now how can I publish to Github Pages.

Answer (score 4):

Use one of the Github Pages actions.

On one of my projects I've used [JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action](https://github.com/JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action). Here's [an example](https://github.com/jakzal/mastermind-kotlin/blob/master/.github/workflows/docs.yml):

```yaml
name: Docs
on:
  push:
    branches: [master]
jobs:
  publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          persist-credentials: false
      - name: Set up JDK
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 11
      - name: Build documentation
        run: ./gradlew asciidoctor
      - name: Publish documentation
        uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@releases/v3
        with:
          ACCESS_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN }}
          BRANCH: gh-pages
          FOLDER: build/docs
```

You'll need to adapt the build step to your build process and tweak the path where the docs are generated.

You'll also need to define the `ACCESS_TOKEN` secret (Settings -> Secrets in your repository). The token can be generate in your profile Settings -> Developer Settings -> Personal access tokens.

There's more actions to choose from , i.e. https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-pages-action, so do your research and choose the one that suits you best.

Answer (score 0):

**Add Dokka to project `build.gradle.kts`**

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.dokka") version "1.9.10"
}

tasks{
    register<Jar>("dokkaJar") {
        from(dokkaHtml)
        dependsOn(dokkaHtml)
        archiveClassifier.set("javadoc")
    }
}
```

**Add Github Action**

```yaml
name: Docs

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]

 ## Delete below when merged to main!
 ## Added such that one can test pages deployment on branch before merging
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ] 

jobs:
  publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          persist-credentials: false

      - name: Set up JDK 21
        uses: actions/setup-java@v4
        with:
          java-version: 21
          distribution: 'adopt'

      - name: Build documentation
        run: ./gradlew dokkaHtml

      - name: Publish documentation
        uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@releases/v4
        with:
          BRANCH: gh-pages
          FOLDER: build/dokka/html
```

Run it once for it to create your new `gh-pages` git branch.

**Enable Github Pages for your repository**

- Project -> Settings -> Pages tab
- Source: `Deploy from a branch`
- Branch: `gh-pages`

[image: Github Pages Setup]

---

To summarize, you may use this Github Action: https://github.com/JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action 
 
To use it you need to create your own Github Action that:

- Builds the Dokka website: `./gradlew dokkaHtml`
- Invokes the JamesIves Github Action

  - Passing it where the newly built website can be found: `build/dokka/html/`
  - Passing it a git branch name to where it can copy the site onto `gh-pages`

Then setup the repo's Github Pages to point to the branch `gh-pages`. 
 
Every time you run your Docs Github Action it'll generate a Dokka site, copy it to `gh-pages`, which Github Pages points to publish to `https://{userid}.github.io/{repo_name}`

Check out my example here: https://github.com/seljabali/java-time-fun/